# how to config the url-loader in webpack to transform only some folders?

Tags: webpack, urlloader, webpack-file-loader

**webpack.js**

file.jpg: transform to base64 by url-loader

file.png: use file-loader

just use the ext to decide all file.jpg in project to transform。

but how to deal the file.gif?

indeed I want to know how to config the url-loader in webpack to transform only some folders or some files?but not just all files of some types.

sorry,my english is poor...

```js
rules:{
    {
        test: /\.(png|svg|ttf|eot|woff|otf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.(gif|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',//url-loader?limit=30000
        options: {
            limit:30000,
            name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]',
        },
        exclude: ////don't know how to config
    }
}
```

[**Directory Structures**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpI2N.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exclude one path:

```
exclude: /my_excluded_path/
```

To exclude multiple paths:

```
exclude: [
    /my_excluded_path/,
    /my_other_excluded_path/
]
```

Excluding a specific absolute path instead of using a regular expression:

```
exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "my_excluded_path")
```

Comment: thanks... I use the  regular expression and string path before.

Answer (score 1):

**Excluding a specific absolute path instead of using a regular expression**

```js
{
    test: /\.(gif|jpg|png|svg|ttf|eot|woff|otf)$/,//(png|jpg|gif|svg)
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]'
    },
    exclude:  [path.join(projectRoot, './vue/img')]
},
{
    test: /\.(gif|png|jpg)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
        limit:30000,
        name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]',
    },
    exclude:  [path.join(projectRoot, './vue/image')]
}
```